# ASP.NET Automapper add to list of objects in map profile

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

To create PersonalChatDto

1. I first create dto and map Chat class into it
2. Map member options to existing dto
3. Map partner(user I talk to) to existing dto
4. And if partner is in contact book, i want mapper to take value of `List<AvatarDto> Avatars` and add avatar from contact to it.

```
var partner = chat.Members.Single(u => u.Id != user.Id);

        var contact = await contactRepository.GetContactAsync(user.Id, partner.Id);

        var member = await personalChatMemberRepository.GetMemberAsync(chat.Id, user.Id);

        var dto = mapper.Map<PersonalChatDto>(chat);
        mapper.Map(member, dto);
        mapper.Map(partner, dto);
        mapper.Map(contact, dto);

        return Result<PersonalChatDto>.Success(dto);
```

The problem is in mapping profile it shows me

```
var avatars = destMember ?? [];
var contactAvatar = src.CustomAvatar;
```

All props have correct values and even returns correct values.

1. [avatars value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbzjx.png)
2. [contactAvatar value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA1KI.png)
3. [return value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyYhT.png)

But after all mappings dto's Avatars field is empty list

1. [dto object after all maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYJtx.png)
2. [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhvat.png)

Here is mapping profile

```
CreateMap<Contact, PersonalChatDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id,
                opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt =>
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomFirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt =>
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomLastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Avatars, opt =>
                opt.MapFrom((src, _, destMember, context) =>
                {
                    var avatars = destMember ?? [];
                    var contactAvatar = src.CustomAvatar;

                    if (contactAvatar is null) return avatars;
                    
                    avatars.Add(context.Mapper.Map<AvatarDto>(contactAvatar));
                    
                    return avatars;
                }));
```

Contact class

```
public sealed class Contact : IEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }

    public User Owner { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public string CustomFirstName { get; set; }

    public string? CustomLastName { get; set; }

    public Guid CustomAvatarId { get; set; }

    public ContactAvatar? CustomAvatar { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

PersonalChatDto record

```
public sealed record PersonalChatDto(
    [Required] Guid Id,
    [Required] string UserName,
    [Required] string FirstName,
    string? LastName,
    string? Biography,
    List<AvatarDto>? Avatars,
    [Required] bool IsMuted)
{
    public PersonalChatDto() 
        : this(default, default!, default!, null, null, null, default)
    {
    }
};
```

I was trying to configure map profile to add to list of existing items, instead of setting new value.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and set its title to summarize the problem you are having with AutoMapper, rather than simply naming it. See [ask], the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ValueResolver by auto mapper

```
CreateMap<Contact, PersonalChatDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Id,
            opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt =>
            opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomFirstName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt =>
            opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomLastName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Avatars, opt => opt.MapFrom<CustomResolver>());
```

Resolver class will look like

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<Source, Destination, int>
{
    public int Resolve(Source source, Destination destination, int member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.Value1 + source.Value2;
    }
}
```

you should change the TDestmember as you need

Also you should register this custome resolver as a service in the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<CustomResolver>();
```

check https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#custom-value-resolvers

Comment: I tried your solution, but it works exactly the same way. I guess 
`.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) =>` is the same as
`.MapFrom<Resolver>()` as long as resolver has the same parameters. I believe it's just about code separation. But still thanks

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, you pointed me in the right direction, ty

Answer (score 0):

i just returned new result object with added User avatars and Contact avatar

```
public sealed class ContactAvatarPersonalChatDtoResolver : IValueResolver<Contact, PersonalChatDto, List<AvatarDto>?>
{
    public List<AvatarDto> Resolve(
        Contact source, PersonalChatDto destination, List<AvatarDto>? destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        List<AvatarDto> result = [];
        
        if(destMember?.Count > 0)
            result.AddRange(destMember);
        if(source.CustomAvatar != null)
            result.Add(context.Mapper.Map<AvatarDto>(source.CustomAvatar) with
            {
                AvatarPriority = AvatarPriority.Custom
            });

        return result;
    }
}
```